# For each class in directory

Tags: php, symfony, class, design-patterns

I'm facing a question, I'm making a command on Symfony which is supposed to launch different operations (undefined for the moment) so I would like to create a directory, put all operations in different files but in this directory and browse it when the command is launched.

```
/MyCommand.php
/Verifications/CheckUser.php
/Verifications/CheckEmail.php
/Verifications/...
```

Do you have a better way to avoid to declare them into MyCommand ?
Any design pattern ? How can I get all those class ?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are them command you need to execute in `MyCommand`?

If you're on symfony > 3.3 you can take advantage of [`autoconfigure`](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-service-autoconfiguration), assign a custom tag (automatically with `autoconfigure`) and fetch them as you need ([here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#create-a-compiler-pass) you can find an example; maybe you'll not going to need `CompilerPass` but the concept is the same)

If you're on symfony < 3.3 you need to tag them explicitly and fetch when you need.

With this methodology you're not even bounded to file location on your `src` (or whatever) directory as long as Symfony can discover those services (or as long as you declare them explicitly) and tag them

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually I'm using Symfony 4, your answer could be a way better than mine but can I do a kind of "for each service" after got them all ?

Comment: @D.Schreier of course you can, you'll get them in array after fetching

Comment: Great ! I didn't know that you got an array when you fetch them all.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: It seems that I can't do it without CompilerPass, do you have a way to do without ?

Comment: @D.Schreier Access services directly if them are declared public but it's better to do with CompilerPass